# Deep linking in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I'm using [Custom Url Scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) to allow deep linking to my ionic app.  But in addition to opening the app, I want the path passed with the deep link to open the correct state.  Does the below approach (which is working) pose any issues? Or is there a cleaner way to address?

Test link: `myapp://somepath`

1. User clicks link, which opens the app
2. [Custom Url Scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) calls `handleOpenUrl(url)`, which saves `somepath` into the local storage before opening the app
3. `$ionicplatform.on('resume'...)` calls `checkExternalUrl`, which checks the local storage for `externalUrl` and, if it finds a path saved there, then navigates to that path using `window.location.href`

www/app/js/app.js:

```js
function handleOpenURL(url) {
  var path = url.slice(8) // strips away myapp://
  window.localStorage.setItem("externalUrl", path);
}

angular.module('myapp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $localstorage) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        function checkExternalUrl(){
          var externalUrl = $localstorage.get('externalUrl', false)
          if (externalUrl){
            window.location.href = '#' + externalUrl
            $localstorage.removeItem('externalUrl')
          }
        }

        $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
          checkExternalUrl()
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ionic 2 has its own pattern, and it differs from Angular 2 routing. It's DeepLinker, described [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/DeepLinker/).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [these guidelines](https://medium.com/angularjs-articles/deep-linking-in-ionic-mobile-applications-44d8b4685bb3) and also use a timeout.

Your problems depend on how and where you are using the plugin. For example, if you are using it with social share plugin then you have to pass the state with share functionality and hence you probably have to be more aware of how the code will work.

Comment: It would be nice if you would add some details to your answer. Links might not be available in some time.